# Trading maps with poemap.live

Tags: path-of-exile

[Poemap.live](https://poemap.live/) can be used to search for people who have the maps you don't have while needing the maps you have extra of. This sounds like a great solution to improve mapping in Path of exile. Especially this league where I keep getting the same maps, almost like some maps are blocked. There's also a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RzUo9NbLnWk) showing how this can be done.

However the site hasn't found any potential trades for me yet. I've tried:
- Different time zones
- Offered 2 maps on tier 3, 3 maps on tier 4 and 1 map on tier 5 (the only ones I have)
- Requested 7 maps on tier 3, 7 maps on tier 4 and 9 maps on tier 5
- For Hardcore Legion
- Keep playing while the site is looking for trades

One of the tooltip says:

> IF YOU CLICK "READY", THE USER WILL KNOW THAT YOU ARE READY TO EXCHANGE. EVERYONE ELSE WILL SEE "BUSY" AND WILL NOT DISTURB YOU.

Am I correct in thinking this only applies after it's found a potential trade?
Or am I forgetting to press a button somewhere?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question pertains to a 3rd party, non-affiliated game service (in this case, poemap.live, which allows uers to exchange maps), and not actually applying to the game itself.

Comment: As the answer mentioned, you are using the site correctly. The problem is just that not everyone who plays knows about or uses the site, as well as being pretty late into the league. This is all compounded onto the fact you are in the hardcore league which also has a smaller playerbase that softcore.

Comment: /r/pathofexile is a great place to ask these questions relating to path of building, poemap or poe.trade - Arqade doesn't allow anything that isn't straight from the game creators themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tool is working mostly in the first month of the league. In the second month, people are leaving the game and online on PoeMap is not comfortable for exchanging low tiers.
The third month is not popular for Path of Exile at all and sometimes GGG starts new Flashback events.

Right now you are in almost the third month.

The mentioned tooltip is not related to the problem.